# How to read first and last name with void function

Tags: c++, void

I can easily create a void function to output something like a header, but I cannot get a program to read a user's input and then output it to them.

ie. Have a program say "Please enter your first name" and then output "You entered: (what they put)"

An example of what I have:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<iomanip>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

void namefn()//namefn prototype

int main(){
    string firstName,lastName;
    return 0;
}

void namefn(string firstName, string lastName){
    cout<<"please enter your first and last name "<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `cin` to read, is in [iostream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/).

i.e.

```
cin >> firstName;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cout << "enter your first and last name:";
cin >> firstName >> lastName;
cout << firstName << " " << lastName;
```

if you want the program to display the first name and last name separately then this:

```
cout << "enter you first name:";
cin >> firstName;
cout << firstName << endl;
cout << "Enter your last name:";
cin >> lastName;
cout << lastName << endl;
```

Comment: How is your answer different from the one posted by @21koizyd earlier?

Comment: He or she wrote the entire program but I wanted to show Sarah how to get the first and last name together and separately. I didn't copy @21koizyd if that is what you're thinking I posted before him or her. I am new to SO so if I did something wrong please tell me I don't want to provide wrong answers or anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void displayFirstAndLast(const std::string& firstName, const std::string& lastName)
{
     std::cout << "You are " << firstName << " " << lastName << std::endl;
}


int main(){
     std::string firstName;
     std::string lastName;
     std::cout << "Please enter your first and last name " << std::endl;
     std::cin >> firstName >> lastName;
     displayFirstAndLast(firstName, lastName);
     return 0;
}
```

I think, that you want something like this.

Or with something like "header"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void displayFirstAndLast(const std::string& firstName, const std::string& lastName);

int main(){
     std::string firstName;
     std::string lastName;
     std::cout << "Please enter your first and last name " << std::endl;
     std::cin >> firstName >> lastName;
     displayFirstAndLast(firstName, lastName);
     return 0;
}

void displayFirstAndLast(const std::string& firstName, const std::string& lastName)
{
     std::cout << "You are " << firstName << " " << lastName << std::endl;
}
```